# Grading System - Input Features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, data-science

I am working on a Grading System ( graduation project ). I have preprocessed the data, then used TfidfVectorizer on the data and used LinearSVC to fit the model.

The System goes as follows, it has 265 definitions, of arbitrary lengths; but in total, they sum up to shape of (265, 8581 )
so when I try to input some new random sentence to predict against it, I get this message

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGzB2.png)

you could have a look at the code used ( Full & long ) if you want to;

Code used;

```
def normalize(df):
    lst = []
    for x in range(len(df)):
        text = re.sub(r"[,.'!?]",'', df[x])
        lst.append(text)
    filtered_sentence = ' '.join(lst)
    return filtered_sentence


def stopWordRemove(df):
    stop = stopwords.words("english")
    needed_words = []
    for x in range(len(df)):

        words = word_tokenize(df)
        for word in words:
            if word not in stop:
                needed_words.append(word)
    return needed_words


def prepareDataSets(df):
    sentences = []
    for index, d in df.iterrows():
        Definitions = stopWordRemove(d['Definitions'].lower())
        Definitions_normalized = normalize(Definitions)
        if d['Results'] == 'F':
            sentences.append([Definitions, 'false'])
        else:
            sentences.append([Definitions, 'true'])
    df_sentences = DataFrame(sentences, columns=['Definitions', 'Results'])
    for x in range(len(df_sentences)):
        df_sentences['Definitions'][x] = ' '.join(df_sentences['Definitions'][x])
    return df_sentences

def featureExtraction(data):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10, max_df=0.75, ngram_range=(1,3))
    tfidf_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    return tfidf_data

def learning(clf, X, Y):
    X_train, X_test,  Y_train, Y_test = \
    cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=.2,random_state=43)
    classifier = clf()
    classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    predict = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(classifier, X_test, Y_test, cv=5)
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, X_test, Y_test, cv=5)
    print(scores)
    print ("Accuracy of %s: %0.2f(+/- %0.2f)" % (classifier, scores.mean(), scores.std() *2))
    print (classification_report(Y_test, predict))
```

Then I run these scripts : which I get the mentioned error after

```
test = LinearSVC()
data, target = preprocessed_df['Definitions'], preprocessed_df['Results']
tfidf_data = featureExtraction(data)
X_train, X_test,  Y_train, Y_test = \
cross_validation.train_test_split(tfidf_data,target, test_size=.2,random_state=43)
test.fit(tfidf_data, target)
predict = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(test, X_test, Y_test, cv=10)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(test, X_test, Y_test, cv=10)
print(scores)
print ("Accuracy of %s: %0.2f(+/- %0.2f)" % (test, scores.mean(), scores.std() *2))
print (classification_report(Y_test, predict))
Xnew = ["machine learning is playing games in home"]
tvect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=1.0, ngram_range=(1,3))
X_test= tvect.fit_transform(Xnew)
ynew = test.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Is it possible to paste the full error message? It becomes a bit easier to look for the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @HarisNadeem Thanks for your reply, I have edited the question to add screenshot of error message. kindly have a look!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text. Format it as code.

Comment: You really do have a lot of code for me to read. lol. But from what I can tell, your issue arises from here: `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=1.0, ngram_range=(1,3))`. It looks from the docs that this is causing the shrink of words to 18. Would something like using `TfidfTransformer` instead be better?

Comment: (P.S. I don't know the solution, but I am trying to read the docs and see where the potential error is arising from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `fit_transform()` on test, only `transform()` and use the same vectorizer which is used on training data.

Do this:

```
def featureExtraction(data):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10, max_df=0.75, ngram_range=(1,3))
    tfidf_data = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

    # Here I am returning the vectorizer as well, which was used to generate the training data
    return vectorizer, tfidf_data
...
...
tfidf_vectorizer, tfidf_data = featureExtraction(data)
...
...

# Now using the same vectorizer on test data
X_test= tfidf_vectorizer.transform(Xnew)
...
```

In your code, you are using a new TfidfVectorizer which obviously will not know about the training data and also not know that training data has 8581 features.

The test data should be prepared in the same way as you prepare the train data, always. Else even if you not get error, the results are wrong and model will not perform like that in real case scenarios.

See my other answers explaining similar situation for different feature preprocessing techniques:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205199/3374996
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461140/3374996
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671967/3374996

I would have tagged this question as a duplicate of one of these, but seeing you are using a new vectorizer altogether and have a different method for transforming train data, I answered this. From next time, please search the issue first and try understanding whats happening in similar scenarios, before posting a question.